# how to remove Duplicate data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to show all data if column E and G are match, and do not show duplicate data in new column I use this formula but I have 2 problems:

- it generates 3 column but I just want same data
- it does not remove duplicate data

my formula is:

```
=BYROW(UnIQUE(E1:E14),LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,{ax,JOIN(",",FILTER(F1:F14,E1:E14=ax)),XLOOKUP(ax,E1:E14,G1:G14,)})))
```

how show result just like column J in one column?

[image]

I just want J column as output but formula show me I,J,K as output. and remove duplicate data in J and show every data just once

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75010528/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Do A and B have to match?. If so, you can use this formula by joining all values in B that match to each unique value in A, then splitting them and finding unique values. Is that what you expect?, how does column C interacts?, it has 4444 and 5555 as values for the same value in A, but it doesn't appear in your output.

```
=LAMBDA(a,{a,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(each,
JOIN(",",UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",FILTER(B:B,A:A=each)),",",1,1))))))})
(FILTER(UNIQUE(A:A),UNIQUE(A:A)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks your formula remove duplicate data but 2 problem, in my example I want every time 4444 and 141 are same then data of column f show in your formula you just check one column, and your output show in 2 column how i can just show column f in your solution

Comment: That's why I asked. Should you divide results by both columns? Let's say one row for 141 and 4444, and another for 141 and 5555?, or you also want in column C to be in one row and show "4444,5555". That's not very clear in your example nor explanation, could you specify more?